# Error 2104: Could not Load Sivlerlight Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, cassini

**[The 2104 error has now "magically" disappeared and I don't know (yet) what changed - so please don't spend time on this. I will post back if/when I figure out what caused the original problem.]**

Running SL4, Win7, VS2010 SP1 and this problem occurs while debugging the app(s). I have two distinct SL apps (projects) and they are in different VS2010 Solutions. I'm using the default debug web server (Cassini?). App #1 contains a hyperlink to App #2, but when I click that hyperlink I get the subject error message.

App #1 is also a SL4 app and the linking is done with code in a handler:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(uri, "_blank");
```

I've checked the uri in the debugger and it looks right. Identical code in another handler works OK (linking to a different target.)

App #1 is hosted on localhost:45621 while App #2 is hosted on localhost:55562. App #2 web server is already running at the time I click the hyperlink in App #1. Also, If I take the URL associated with the hyperlink that is clicked and simply paste it into a fresh browser address bar then App #2's SL page opens without problems.
I have clientaccesspolicy.xml files for both Apps:

```
<access-policy> 
  <cross-domain-access> 
    <policy> 
      <allow-from> 
    <domain uri="*"/> 
      </allow-from> 
      <grant-to> 
    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/> 
      </grant-to> 
    </policy> 
  </cross-domain-access> 
</access-policy>
```

I'm at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this at this point and would appreciate any suggestions as to what the cause might be -- or how to further isolate the problem.
Thanks in advance,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

please confirm if what I understand is your setup:

Web project #1
Html Page
`<a href="page in other project"...`

Web project #2
Html or Aspx page
Your silverlight application is here

Comment: No, App#1 is also a SL4 app. I've updated the original post with more detail on this aspect.  Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. did the testing with two solutions and, even with no clientaccesspolicy file (because I think Silverlight is the one restricted but the HTML page is not, I got the second Silverlight project opened twice no problem.

Try to do it from scratch and see if still get that problem.

Comment: Is your Uri something like this?: Uri U = new Uri("http://localhost:63151/SilverTest4TestPage.aspx", UriKind.Absolute);

Comment: Well, the 2104 error has "magically" disappeared now and the page is loading. At this point I have no idea what has changed. I've updated the post to reflect this. I'm going to spend some time trying to figure out what "fixed" it. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Don't worry it happens to everyone... there are leprechauns everywhere messing with everything :o)